# Errors when checking status of just installed MariaDB 10.3 database

Tags: mariadb, centos7

I have just installed MariaDB 10.3 database server in Centos 7.

All went well, but when executing "systemctl status mariadb" command. This is the full output:

```
root@vps [/etc/init.d]# systemctl status mariadb
● mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.3.13 database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2019-02-24 22:34:04 -03; 40min ago
     Docs: man:mysqld(8)
           https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/systemd/
 Main PID: 12247 (mysqld)
   Status: "Taking your SQL requests now..."
   CGroup: /system.slice/mariadb.service
           └─12247 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Feb 24 22:46:39 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:46:39 32 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch..._upgrade
Feb 24 22:46:39 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:46:39 32 [ERROR] InnoDB: Column last_update in table `mysql`.`innodb_table_st...smatch).
Feb 24 22:46:39 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:46:39 32 [ERROR] InnoDB: Fetch of persistent statistics requested for table `...instead.
Feb 24 22:46:40 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:46:40 37 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. ...is error
Feb 24 22:46:40 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:46:40 37 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column '...TE','POS
Feb 24 22:46:41 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:46:41 45 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table mysql.event: expected column '...TE','POS
Feb 24 22:49:43 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:49:43 47 [Warning] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Feb 24 22:49:43 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:49:43 48 [Warning] Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Feb 24 22:49:57 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:49:57 55 [Warning] InnoDB: Table mysql/innodb_table_stats has length mismatch..._upgrade
Feb 24 22:49:57 vps.desytec.com mysqld[12247]: 2019-02-24 22:49:57 55 [ERROR] InnoDB: Column last_update in table `mysql`.`innodb_table_st...smatch).
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

Database is up, however, I want to solve the errors there. For example, problems with missing columns in tables or the access to admin@localhost user.

To try to solve the admin user problem, I have created that user and grant all privileges, but it is still showing that error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Looks as if there was a previous install already, running the mysql_upgrade tool should fix the system tables and bring them to the right structure for the version you have installed now.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mysql_upgrade/

Comment: I have run "# mysql_upgrade --force | grep 'mysql.event'" and console showed "mysql.event                                        OK", however, when running again "systemctl status mariadb" it still shows the errors starting with: "Incorrect definition of table mysql.event" and all other errors too.

Comment: Ok, not as easy as usual then ... what does "SHOW CREATE TABLE mysql.event;" report, and what "mysql_upgrade --version"?